# Share a global variable between c files

Tags: c, extern

I have the following files:

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

int main()
{
    print();
    add_one();
    print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

**main2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

int main()
{
    print();
    add_one();
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

**library.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

int number = 0;

void add_one(){
    number++;
}

void print()
{
    printf("number: %d\n", number);
}
```

**library.h**

```
extern int number;

void add_one();
void print();
```

When I run main first and then main2, I get the same:
number: 0
number: 1
It shouldn't come out as number: 0 and number: 1 for main, but for main2, it should be number: 1 and number: 2.
Any idea why this happens?

Comment: When you run a program all variables are dropped when the program exits. If you run another program it will not remember state of it self or other programs before it self. If you want to save the state of the number variable it needs to be written to some storage medium.

Comment: You have two separate programs, why because the first main act as the first program and the  second act as the second program so for each program the number has a different address if you want to get `1 for main, but for main2, it should be number: 1 and number: 2. Any idea why this happens?` you should have two functions and call them in one main

Comment: This is a great first question! Good job on sharing your code and creating a minimal example that illustrates what you're asking about. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

> It shouldn't come out as number: 0 and number: 1 for main, but for
> main2, it should be number: 1 and number: 2. Any idea why this
> happens?

No, because `main` and `main2` are two different programs and they do not share the variable `number` between them. It is always initialized to zero at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run main first and then main2, I get the same: number: 0 number: 1 It shouldn't come out as number: 0 and number: 1 for main, but for main2, it should be number: 1 and number: 2. Any idea why this happens?

Each different program that you build against your library will get its own copy of the library, including any variables that the library defines. The two programs don't share data just because they both use the same library. If you want to share data between `main` and `main2`, you'll need to arrange for some sort of common data storage. That sort of thing invites all kinds of problems where two programs both modify the shared data at the same time, so be very careful.

Indeed, even if you run `main` and then run `main` again, you're going to get the same value printed both times because the library isn't storing its data anywhere. `number` is going to be initialized to 0 every time the program runs.